# How to add a pod with a vendored_framework as a dependency to another pod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

The case (all names are not real):

- I have a `Lib` pod with a vendored_framework (an obj-c static library)
- Need to make another `SDK` pod (swift dynamic framework)
- Need to add the `Lib` as a dependency to `SDK`

If I'm adding both `Lib` and `SDK` pods into my app's Podfile they are working great and both are available from the app.

But when I'm trying to add `Lib` as `spec.dependency` into the `SDK.podspec` and include only local SDK to the app (`pod 'SDK', :path => '../../SDK'`) I'm receiving this error after `pod install`:

```
[!] The 'Pods-my-app' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Path/to/the/Lib/static/library.a)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or this is [not yet implemented](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-packager/pull/119), or it's a bug?

Comment: anything on this?